# Expired Sub Certificate

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate

I'm running into an issue where 4 client windows computers out of a 200+ are still showing an expired cert from one of our websites (hosted externally) even though we added the new cert to the website.

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRjrT.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnR4E.png)

I've checked the normal locations for the Certificates (MMC, certificates (local user and computer), and through Chrome and IE which seem to point to the same store. Also checked firefox's separate store) and the best I have been able to find is the intermediate level CA that allowed the cert in the first place.

I validated we are not running any http caching on the firewall nor is this an issue with the hosted website (ran a capture, and the client computer is not pulling the cert data from the site)

Is there way I can find where this is cached and clear it either through the registry, browser (already tried clearing SSL state) and/or through any certificate store?

[Local store viewed through Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnR4E.png)

Any help would be appreciated,

thank you,

Justin Jones
System Administrator